# If $f'(c)$ exists prove that $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> **Problem.**
>   Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $f'(c)$ exists. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $c$.

Does this proof make any sense?

The Mean Value Theorem states that if $f$ is continuous on an interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)$ exists.

From the information given, we know that:

- $f'(c)$ exists.
- $c \in \mathbb{R}$

So in accordance with the MVT, $f$ must also be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The converse of the MVT is not true in general.

Comment: You are assuming what you are supposed to prove.

Comment: @youngsmasher could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @zdmwi you can use the mean value theorem only when the function is continuous

Comment: You only have that $f$ is differentiable at $c$. The The Mean Value Theorem requires that $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @zdmwi Just because $f'(c)$ exists and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ doesn't mean that $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. A counter-example would be $|x|$ and taking $c = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(c)$ is continuous iff $\lim_{h\to0}f(c+h)-f(c)=0$(by definition), the definition of derivative is $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}h$, this limit exists only if $\lim_{h\to0}{f(c+h)-f(c)}=0$ and you are done

Answer (score 0):

$f(c+h)-f(c)= \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}\cdot h \to f'(c) \cdot 0=0$  as $h \to 0$.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @user170039 it shows that $f(c+h)-f(c)=0$, so by definition it is continuous

Comment: It shows that $ \lim_{h \to 0}f(c+h)=f(c)$.

Comment: But OP didn't want a proof of the fact. He/she simply wanted to check his proof. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the MVT as it doesn't say anything about the derivative implying continuity. Its not an if and only if statement..

$f'(c)$ exists. Put $f'(c)=L$

So

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} = L$$

and therefore, given $\epsilon >0,$ $\exists \delta>0 $ such that $h<\delta $ implies $|\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} -L|<\epsilon$.

So multiplying by $h>0$ we get $$|f(c+h) - f(c) -h L|<\epsilon$$
And $f$ is continuous at $c$ as $h \to 0$.

Rudin has a theorem about this that you might be interested in checking out.